# Content script not invoked for some URLs

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my manifest.xml, I have content script as follows:

```
"content_scripts": [    
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*/*"                
            ],
            "js": ["xyz.js"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "run_at": "document_idle"
        }
```

It gets invoked for almost all the urls starting with http, https or even with URLs starting with "file://". But for pdfs that I open with pdf.js the url becomes something like :`chrome-extension://namhfjepbaaecpmpgehfppgnhhgaflne/content/web/viewer.html?file=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifets.info%2Fjournals%2F10_4%2F9.pdf`

---

In these cases I the content script is not invoked. Is there any known reason behind this? Or am I not using content scripts correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pdf.js is an extension which opens pdfs on its own page with chrome-extension:// protocol. This protocol [isn't supported](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) for content scripts. The reason is that extensions use privileged APIs and hence designed to be isolated from "hijacking" by another extension via content scripts and such.

If pdf.js is part of your own extension it's possible to manually add the content script to the extension's own html page (`content/web/viewer.html` in your case):

```html
<head>
    <script src="xyz.js"></script>
</head>
```

P.S. instead of `*://*/*` use `<all_urls>` as per [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

Comment: My extension actually uses pdf.js to load the pdf. So that url I mentioned in the question is ID of my own extension. In this case, should I add the script to pdf js scripts instead of content scripts?